# Parse n level deep JSON in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc

Supposingly I have a json as follows: -

```
{
    "name":"WorkBook",
    "type":"xs:string",
    "complexType": {
        "name":"EmpID",
        "type":"xs:string",
        "complexType": {
            "name":"Salary",
            "type":"xs:string",
            "complexType":null
        }
    }
}
```

I am producing this json from a `Spring controller`, which consumes a `xsd`. The json is passed on to my `angularJS` controller.
The 'complexType' can be n-levels deep.

My requirement is to `parse this json in AngularJS/jsp` and create a `hierarchial tree like structure` for the same, somewhat like http://www.jstree.com/docs/html/ .
(Non collapse-able and simpler would do)

Any suggestions how to go about it? (Using ng-repeat or something, assuming I have the json in a variable called 'xsdContents'.

If it all I need to add extra parameters to json, such as level number or something, that is also possible.

Comment: Is this the one http://plnkr.co/edit/6BorEN9Tht5bezmkfys9?p=preview

Comment: Somewhat yes. Found a better solution, posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of a research, found this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">
    {{ category.title }}
    <ul ng-if="category.categories">
        <li ng-repeat="category in category.categories" ng-include="'categoryTree'">           
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/NP7P5/

Source:

```
http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates
```

Thanks anyway :)